# How to make swift binary framework (xcframework) for supporting iPad devices

Tags: swift, ipad, frameworks, xcframework, dynamic-frameworks

I am quit new in making swift frameworks and i have been working on my framework that supports iOS devices but i don't know how to make one for iPad devices.

What I did is that, I build my framework for iOS device in Xcode and exported the framework into my target app where i want to use this. This is working fine for iPhone devices but if i try to run the app on iPad then it crashed, i have given support for iPad devices in my project.
I am trying to create a xcFramework using commands specified by apple :
xcodebuild archive 
-scheme SimpleMath 
-destination "generic/platform=iOS" 
-archivePath ../output/SimpleMath 
SKIP_INSTALL=NO 
BUILD_LIBRARY_FOR_DISTRIBUTION=YES

Can anyone help me how to support my framework for both iPhone and iPad devices? I read that we can create two xcFrameworks for iPhone and simulator and then combine them to universal framework, i am thinking there must be similar something like for iPhone and iPad devices.
Any help and suggestions will be highly  helpful for me.

Thanks

Comment: You don't need to build a framework specifically for iPadOS. You should look at the details of your crash. You do need to ensure your code behaves correctly on the iPad platform. A crash indicates that your code probably doesn't correctly adapt to iPad.

Comment: Thanks @Paulw11 for correcting me that we don't need specific framework for iPad.